# What is the charge of an electric field created by an oscillating magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, charge, maxwell-equations

An oscillating (or, even accelerating) magnetic field produces an electric field. What is the charge of that electric field?

Comment: What do you mean by "the charge of an electric field"? Objects have charge, not fields.

Comment: You can have a completely empty space and still some electromagnetic field (just consider the Maxwell equations in the absence of matter). Plane-wave solutions in vacuum are probably the simplest textboox example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_wave_equation

Comment: By "charge of the field" do you mean, the charge that CAUSES the field? In which case, it depends on what magnetic field is produced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the charge of that electric field?

The charge of that electric field is 0.

The charge is proportional to the divergence of the electric field, and the electric field produced by a changing magnetic field has no divergence.

Answer (score 0):

Electric and magnetic fields do not create electric charges, they can only act on them. An electric field can separate charges. A magnetic field can align the magnetic dipoles of the charges.

---

tl;dr

Perhaps your sentence "oscillating magnetic field produces an electric field" refers to a circuit under alternating current.

Since every circuit for alternating current has the properties of both the coil (inductance) and the capacitor (capacitance), there is a phase shift of the current to the voltage.

The carriers of the two fields there are the moving electrons. By separating the charges at the capacitor, an electric field is formed and by the acceleration in the circuit in the coil, the magnetic field is formed. The moving electrons emit electromagnetic radiation (power loss of any circuit).

In the extreme case, the circuit looks like this:
[image]

If wanted, this circuit can emit a particularly large amount of power as loss. Then one has built an antenna transmitter. The photons emitted by the surface electrons form a common electric and a common magnetic field that oscillates away from the source at the speed of light.